# Append of Tables with the Same Variables but Differing Attributes

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

My question is about the append of two different tables that are supposed to have the same name/format/type/length variables.

I am trying to create a step in my SAS program where I don't allow my program to be executed if the format/type/length of variables with the same name is not the same. 
For example, when in one table I have a date in type string "dd-mm-yyyy" and in the other table I have the "yyyy-mm-dd" or "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss". After the append, our daily executions based on these input tables didn't work as expected. Sometimes the values come up as missing or out of order, since the formats are different.

I tried using the PROC COMPARE statement, which allowed me to check which variables have Differing Attributes (Type, Length, Format, InFormat and Labels).

```
proc compare base = SAS-data-set
             compare = SAS-data-set;
run;
```

However, I only got the info on which variables have differing atributes (listing of common variables with differing attributes), not being able to do anything with/about it.

On the other hand, I would like to know if there's a chance to have a structured output table with this information, in order to use it as a control statement.
Creating an automatic task to do it would save me a lot of time.

Screenshot of an example:

[image: Screenshot of an example]

Comment: if possible, please show your  sample input datasets and sample output dataset. someone will able to help you. Please do not show the data in form of code as someone cannot try out your code. An example of how to show your data is in many stackoverflow SAS questions and here is one such link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334541/convert-date-to-string-in-sas-data-step-monyy5-to-yymmn6/54335254#54335254

Comment: "I tried Proc COMPARE...", show the code you tried. If you are using Enterprise Guide, describe the actions you took.

Comment: You have date and datetime variables all mixed into a character column. That's good because you didn't destroy the original data. I would create a new variable, all datetime, and map the shown dates. If you post sample data as text someone can help with that.

Comment: @Richard is this what you meant? (I edited the post)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Proc CONTENTS` to get information about a data sets variables.  Do that for both data sets, and then you can use `Proc COMPARE` to create a data set informing you of the variable attributes differences.

```
data cars1;
  set sashelp.cars (obs=10);
  date = today ();
  format date date9.;
  cars1_only = 1;
  x = 1.458; label x = "x-factor";
run;

data cars2;
  length type $50;
  set sashelp.cars (obs=10);
  format date yymmdd10.;
  cars2_only = 1;
  X = 1.548; label x = "X factor to apply";
run;

proc contents noprint data=cars1 out=cars1_contents;
proc contents noprint data=cars2 out=cars2_contents;
run;

data cars1_contents;
  set cars1_contents;
  upName = upcase(Name);
run;
data cars2_contents;
  set cars2_contents;
  upName = upcase(Name);
run;

proc sort data=cars1_contents; by upName;
proc sort data=cars2_contents; by upName;
run;



proc compare noprint 
  base=cars1_contents 
  compare=cars2_contents 
  outall 
  out=cars_contents_compare (where=(_TYPE_ ne 'PERCENT'))
;

  by upName;
run;
```

There is also an ODS table you can capture directly without having to run `Proc CONTENTS`, but the capture is not 'data-rific'

```
ods output CompareVariables=work.cars_vars;

proc compare base=cars1 compare=cars2;
run;
```